# How to push a UIViewController from a modal view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I present a UIViewController modally but would like to push another ViewController from the modal view. How can this be done as pushViewController does not work from a modal view. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a slightly different approach than Mike's suggestion. I create a navigation controller (NC) and init it with a root viewcontroller of the view controller (VC) I want to present modally. I then present the nc modally. I can then successfully push from the VC when needed.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't being clear, but that's the same approach I described.  I assumed that you would be setting the root as you can't display a nav controller without anything on its stack.  That would be the cause of why you weren't seeing any animation.  The first view put on the nav controller's stack (the root view) is not animated.

Answer (score 2):

Use a UINavigationController as the view that you show modal.  You can then push onto that controller.

Comment: Thanks, this does work, but the push is not being animated despite setting animated to YES

Comment: The reason it did not animate is because the navigation controller did not have a root viewcontroller. I have used a diff approach as below.